# Can't access mySQL remotely with PHP, how to fix?

Tags: php, mysql, database, ubuntu, database-connection

So I have mySQL installed on Ubuntu and I'm trying to access it with PHP.

As long as I'm in Ubuntu, I can access mySQL from the command line without any issues. However, with PHP, I can only connect to mySQL. Once in, though, it refuses to let me select a database. I've enabled all permissions to the user alias that I'm connecting with, and even allowed remote access to the database.

As root, PHP shows the following error:

```
(1049) Unknown database 'my_database'
```

As the user alias I use (called 'default'), PHP shows a different error:

```
(1044) Access denied for user 'default'@'localhost' to database 'my_database'
```

What am I missing? This never happened until I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.11.

Comment: `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'default'@'localhost'`

Comment: @Michael Did your command, got the following results: `GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'default'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'my_database'.* TO 'default'@'localhost'`

Comment: Looks like maybe the user `default` doesn't have a password for `my_database`.  Do `GRANT ALL PRIVILIGES ON 'my_database' TO default@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword';`

Comment: @Michael This gets me a syntax error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''my_database' TO default@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'' at line 1`. I swear, I remember MySQL was much easier a few days ago...

Comment: Sorry , that should be `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO....` with no quotes around `my_database`, and followed by `.*`

Answer (score 0):

Grant your user privileges to that database with the correct password:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_database.* TO default@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'thepassword'
```